# Django: How to show sum of Model field in template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have built the following model:

```
class Fund(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gp = models.ForeignKey(GeneralPartner, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, default="")
    commitment = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def sum_commitment(self):
        return self.commitment
```

I would like to show the sum of all commitments in my template via a simple `{{ fund.sum_commitment }}` tag in my template. What does my return statement has to look like to achieve this goal? I tried things like `return self.sum(commitment)` in all varieties but simply can't find the right solution.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: `commitment` is here a *single* integer, so I do not really understand what you aim to "sum up"?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the sum of all Fund records in your DB?

Comment: all my model entries for the commitment field, so if i have two Funds in my database, the first having a commitment = 10 and the second a commitment = 30, I would like to show the sum, in this case 40 in my template

Comment: yes, exactly the sum of the commitment field for all Fund records

Comment: Well, then it makes no sense for it to be a property. That's a thing that applies to a single instance of Fund, not to all Funds.

Comment: so what could I use instead of a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this using [Aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

@property
def sum_commitment(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.all().aggregate(sum_all=Sum('commitment')).get('sum_all')
```

#### Update

from comments, I am assuming you are using ListView, then you can simply add another variable to the `get_context_data` to add the sum of commitments. For example:

```
class SomeListView(ListView):
    ...


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SomeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['commitment_sum'] = Fund.objects.all().aggregate(sum_all=Sum('commitment')).get('sum_all')
        return context
```

Then access the value in template by `{{ commitment_sum }}`.

Also, there is possibility that you need to reuse this code multiple times, then you can use a [class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), instead of property method like this:

```
@classmethod
def sum_commitment(cls):
    return cls.objects.all().aggregate(sum_all=Sum('commitment')).get('sum_all')
```

And use it in view like this:

```
context['commitment_sum'] = Fund.sum_commitment()
```

Comment: I wonder if there us any advantage in makeing `sum_commitment` a property instead of just a normal method?

Comment: as far as I know, In template, it won't make any difference.

Comment: But as I said above, I don't think this should be a method on the model at all. A classmethod might make more sense, but the more appropriate place for something like this is on the Manager.

Comment: the code from ruddra works, however I can only access the value in my template with a ´{% for fund in object_list %}` loop, so I see the value multiples times as I have multiple records in my database, how can I only use a  simple ´{{ fund.sum_commitment }}´ tag without a loop to show the value only once

Comment: @Daniel I have added an update section to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: the version with the class method worked for me, many thanks @ruddra

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with defining class method in a Model class.